# PM2 logs - how do you write to them

Tags: javascript, pm2

The documentation for PM2 logs is sparse.  In particular it doesn't really tell you what an application log is.

Since my logging requirements are very simple I decided not to go for one of the big logging packages.

The simple question I would like to know is - does that mean console.log?  IE if my application writes to console.log will pm2 capture it and put it in a file?

Comment: I believe PM2 comes with logging? See [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/)

Comment: @aug if you read the documentation in that link (which I had already done) there is no mention of an api to write the logs.  There is plenty of information about how to rotate them, find them and do other things, but not to write an entry in them.  There is a general assumption in all the documentation that you already know the answer, so it doesn't tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the simple way to find the answer - write a simple test script to write to console.log and see where it ends up.

And the answer was that it wrote to a file in my home directory .pm2/logs/test-out-0.log